# clearInterval not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jquery function setinterval and than clearinterval to clear it.. but i the clearinterval is not working .. here is my code.

```
$('#autoslide').click(function(){

    if($('#autoslide').is(':checked')){
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('.magazine').turn('next');


    }, 2000);
    }else
    {

        //stopinterval(interval)
        clearInterval(interval);
        //window.clearInterval(interval);
    //  interval = null
    }
});
```

none of these tries are working

Comment: Understanding variable scope in Javascript is difficult at first, but once you get it, it's hard to ever think differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make your timer variable outside the function.

```
var interval;
$('#autoslide').click(function(){

if($('#autoslide').is(':checked')){
    interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('.magazine').turn('next');


}, 2000);
}else
{

    //stopinterval(interval)
    clearInterval(interval);
    //window.clearInterval(interval);
//  interval = null
}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a global variable. If you use a local variable, each click handler invocation has its own copy of the variable.

```
var interval;
$('#autoslide').click(function(){

    if($('#autoslide').is(':checked')){
        interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('.magazine').turn('next');


    }, 2000);
    }else
    {

        //stopinterval(interval)
        clearInterval(interval);
        //window.clearInterval(interval);
    //  interval = null
    }
});
```